# Ember.js Wildcard URL

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Any ember-way ideas to make a manual transition to a wildcard route with a dynamic segment at the end */:category_name, so I can manually build a "breadcrumbish url version" example, suppose a user enters to /banana I need to transition the user to /Groceries/Healthy/Fruit/Banana.... groceries, healthy, fruit might be entered as well so /Fruit would be transitioned to /Groceries/Healthy/Fruit... I was able to make it work using window.history.replaceState on the model hook of the route but strange enough it only works if it's being refreshed or type in by user, not while transitioning in template, thanks in advance guys

Route as is

```
this.route('products', function(){
   this.route('wildcard_handler', {path: '*/:category_name'});
   this.route('handler', {path: '/:category_name'})
});
```

Recap of cases:

Case 1:

User enters /products/banana

-Redirect to /products/groceries/healthy/fruit/**banana**

User enters /products/fruit

-Redirect to /products/groceries/healthy/**fruit**

Case 2:

User enters /products/**groceries**

-All good, it's correct.

Case 3

User enters /products/groceries/snacks

-doesn't exists so, 404 redirects.

All of this trouble is only for making a better UX for a new ecommerce I'm building, the normal suggested way is to just use one dynamic segment

Like

```
this.route('products', function(){
   this.route('handler', {path: '/:category_name'})
});
```

It's fair, but it's way nicer to build the breadcrumbish url

Again, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Case 1:
If you want to redirect the user to another route before resolving the model, you can use `beforeModel()` hook. You can also use `redirect()` hook to redirect the user to another route. For example (when user visits /products/fruit, you can redirect them to products/groceries/healthy/fruit in `redirect` hook),

```
redirect(model, transition) {
   this._super(...arguments);
   this.transitionTo('products.groceries.healthy.fruit');
}
```

Refer this [link](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.17.0/routing/redirection/#toc-toggle) to know about the predefined hooks in routes.

Case 3:
Refer this [link](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.17.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_wildcard-globbing-routes) to know about wildcarding routes in your application.